# basics of for loops

Tags: matlab, math

I correct the code with help of Stackfriends, see the bold parts, if anybody else has the similiar stack.
Arithmeticaly, I should take w=1 and why get I w=2? Thanks a lot,

```
X=linspace(0,10,6);
Y=linspace(0,20,5);
    Xstar=0;
    Ystar=0;
    **p=0;**
     for i=1:length(X)-1
         for j=1:length(Y)-1
              if (Ystar==Y(j)) && (Xstar==X(i))
                  w=1;
              else
                  w=2;
              end
              **p(i,j)=w**
         end
     end
```

Comment: my question is still above the code. I wonder why I get a mathematically incorrect output? Probably, the error stay in if loop.

Comment: You have to explain what kind of output you are expecting. How are we meant to guess what "mathematically incorrect" means without any information at all?

Comment: In particular, why do you think this code should return w=1?  It looks to me like the w=1 branch is only taken right at the start, when i=1 and j=1.

Comment: @Mr E I've already written it. if grid points (X(i),Y(j)) equal to given points (Xstar,Ystar) then I should get w=1 instead of w=2. I think we cant understand eachother. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: @DSM right, thank you. But can you give me any clue, how to do it: If I want to write for example w=1 for the points equal to grid points and something else for the other poinst(points between grid).

Comment: @user1018331, it's more about us not being able to read your mind and you not being able to express yourself at all.

Comment: @Blindy, Thanks,I'll try to learn it after hard critics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a guess, but i think you want to loop through the arrays backwards. You should use the debugger and look at it step by step.

Try this:

```
...
    for i=length(X):-1:1
         for j=length(Y):-1:1
              if (Ystar==Y(j)) && (Xstar==X(i))
                  w=1;
              else
                  w=2;
              end
         end
     end
```

Here is what you should do to solve the problem.

- set a breakpoint at the beginning of the loop (klick in matlab editor window next to source code, a red point should appear)
- press <kbd>F5</kbd> to start your script, it will stop at your breakpoint
- press <kbd>F10</kbd> to step line by line trough your script, at the same time you can examine the values of your variables e.g. in your workspace window

(I hope these instructions are still valid, I have a rather old version of MATLAB)

Comment: then I get w=0, but I think I see the Idea. Thank you for your kind response.

Comment: @user1018331: `w` should be `1` after executing this.

Comment: thanks again, I got it with your help:)

Answer (score 1):

The assignment `w=1;` is done on only the first loop; every time after that, either `X(i)` or `Y(j)` does not equal 0, so `w=2;` is shown.  After the loops are done, all you will see is `w=2` since you aren't storing the value of all of the iterations.